# Enumerating a class of polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, polynomials, generating-functions, partitions

How many equivalence classes of $\Bbb F_2[x,y]$ polynomials with $x$ degree $n_x$ and $y$ degree $n_y$ are there such that each $y^i$ coefficient (polynomial in $\Bbb Z[x]$) is distinct and $x^i$ coefficient (polynomial in $\Bbb Z[y]$) is distinct?

Two polynomials are equivalent if there is a member of $S_{n_x+1}\times S_{n_y+1}$ changes permutes coefficient of one polynomial to other.

> > Is there a way to give the standard basis for these polynomials (are these a vector space in any sense)?
> >
> > Consider $0/1$ as integers how are these classes organized under $GL_{n_x}(\Bbb R)\times GL_{n_y}(\Bbb R)$ action (muliply coefficient matrix on left and right)?

Is there a $c>0$ such that if $n_y>n_x^c$ then there is no such polynomial for large enough $n_x$, $n_y$?

Comment: Are the polynomials meant to be of degree $n$? Where does the problem come from? Is this a homework question?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas does it look like a hw problem? I will correct degree part.

Comment: There's really no reason to call these polynomials: this is a problem about $(1+n_x) \times (1+n_y)$ arrays of values $\pm 1$ with distinct rows and distinct columns, and you count equivalence classes under permutation of rows and columns.  Each equivalence class has $n_x! n_y!$ members, so the number of equivalence classes is the number of such arrays divided by $n_x! n_y!$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael what about the second and last problem?

Comment: ... or that should be $(n_x+1)!(n_y+1)!$ if you really meant to allow permutations of all the rows and all the columns, rather than just $n_x$ and $n_y$ of them.

Comment: @RobertIsrael then how many such arrays are there?

Comment: Does it look like a HW problem? Yes. Could you tell us more about how it arose? Basically, most arrays should have your properties.

Comment: @AllenKnutson came from comm complexity. I want to understand how these classes are organized per real rank for which the closest I could find was $GL\times GL$ equivalence.

Comment: @AllenKnutson if it is indeed only as difficult as hw problem that will be great. I felt classification with combinatorial and real constraints are hard.

Comment: @RobertIsrael You are over counting. Upper bound is $n_x!n_y!$ (sometime if you permute you may get the same polynomial again).

Comment: @RobertIsrael I mean $(n_x+1)!(n_y+1)!$ is only upper bound and likely loose. I do not think it is that easy.